# boostrap focus input and icon in css

Tags: css, styles, bootstrap-4

how to create focus on two elements?

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="loop-icon form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[no focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTSrx.png)

I would like to get something like that
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiRgi.png)

I don't want to use javascript

Comment: Have you tried using the [CSS :focus Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)?

Comment: it works  only on input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sibling selector " `+` " that will select the next element.

```
.inp:focus + .icon{
  color:red;/* can use any color*/
}
```

This code will select the sibling of input, i.e. the icon class, when the input is focused,

```css
form-group{
position:relative;
}

.icon{
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 11px;
}
.inp{
  padding:right:40px;
}

.inp:focus + .icon{
  color:red;/* can use any color*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inp">
        <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback icon"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```